# Android: Are there any good resources for building Java Only views WITHOUT XML

Tags: android, android-widget, android-custom-view, android-view

I've been going through all of the documentation, and examples found on the web, but I have yet to find any good resources on building custom views using Java ONLY.  I have seen many that describe about creating them using XML and Java.

I think the thing that I'm struggling with the most are relatively simple things like, "can I use a "TextView" widget in a custom view AND also use the canvas to draw some graphics?  I've been successful doing one or the other but can't seem to find ways to do both simultaneously.

For example: I would like to have an TextView widget at the top of a view with a touchable graphic underneath that acts as a dial and is drawn onto the canvas which takes up all available space once the TextView is added.    As I turn the dial, it increments text inside the TextView.  I would think something like the following would work... but it doesn't and it most likely because I'm missing something simple.

```
 public class Dial extends LinearLayout implements View.OnTouchListener
{
    Bitmap _dial;
    protected int bpm = 120;
    TextView txtBpm;    

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context
     */
    public Dial(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        _dial =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dial_small);
        txtBpm = new TextView(context);
        txtBpm.setTextSize(43);
        txtBpm.setWidth(100);
        txtBpm.setText(String.valueOf(bpm));
        this.addView(txtBpm);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
           // Setting the y-pos to 160 so even
           // if the canvas fills the view,
           // the dial will still be below the textview.
        canvas.drawBitmap(_dial, 0,160,null); 
    }   
    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH)
    {

    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.view.View.OnTouchListener#onTouch(android.view.View, android.view.MotionEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
    {
        // Do some stuff here to rotate the dial
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I was hoping to keep it as simple as possible and that I could reuse existing views rather than having to roll my own to methods to control the text properties.  I realize there is overhead with the TextView, but I would think that I could take an existing view and marry it with the existing canvas so I would only have to create a single object that could perform this task.  I come from a Flex background, so I'm used to being able to combine existing controls with the drawing API rather than having to choose one or the other. Seems bloated to have to create 2 classes for something like this.

Comment: Right, except I can include a TextBox inside my custom component, set the height on the component on UpdateDisplayList() and then draw bitmaps(or even standard graphics object) under/around/etc the textbox.  According to your comments regarding my code above, you recommended combining my textview with a custom view = 2 classes.  Is there no way to place a textview inside a custom view AND be able to access the onDraw() at the same time as I have above?  I know my apporach probably isn't the Java way and I'm trying to understand the Java way of approaching this way of creating custom classes.

Comment: Maybe a code example or dissection of my above class would help me understand the approach you are suggesting. I have just found the "demos" and documentation reads like stereo instructions and is less than helpful in understanding the means of including the widgets and graphics inside a custom view.  How would I control the position of the canvas relative to the textbox?  My textview added to the above component, but I seem to missing what I need to do to implement the onDraw() in order to add my touchable bitmap. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So were you able to find any examples Comonsware?  thanks